# Which is the correct form?

Tags: verb-forms

I haven't caught her name, or I didn't catch her name?

Whereby, in which cases should a native use the first or the second form above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I haven't caught her name," implies that you haven't done so **yet**, but that might change in the future.  Meanwhile, "I didn't catch her name" just states a condition, with no expectation or additional nuance.

Consider the following:

> I have caught ten fish
>
> I caught ten fish.

The use of the present perfect tense implies that you're not yet done fishing, and you might catch more.  The use of the past tense simply states a fact, and nothing else.  In the same way:

> I've not caught any fish.

indicates an *ongoing* situation, where you might still catch a fish, while:

> I didn't catch any fish

just says what happened.  Of course I can follow up with a question, to ask if you're still fishing, or if you plan to catch more.  But that information isn't in the statement itself.

To return to your question, a native speaker might say either "haven't caught", or "didn't catch".  It depends on context.  If you're not sure, then "didn't catch" is more generic and should fit with any context.